# How can I migrate a OneToOneField to the related model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have something like this:

```
class A(Model):
    b = OneToOneField('B', related_name='a')

class B(Model):
    pass
```

But for obvious reasons I think my models would be better structured like this:

```
class A(Model):
    pass

class B(Model):
    a = OneToOneField('A', related_name='b')
```

Unfortunately the models are already in production. I'm familiar with `makemigrations`/`migrate` and have had a look through the migration files in the `migrations` directory. I think what I want is to:

1. create an `a` field on `B`, changing `related_name='something_else'`
2. have it initialized using the reverse relation `something_else`
3. remove the `b` field on `A`.

How can I initialize a field in a migration in such a way?

Comment: Thanks, @Alasdair, [data-migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) was exactly what I was after.

Comment: Great, glad it helped :)